# Open windows to preset size and position

Tags: macos, finder

I was wondering if there is a way to create a script or automator task that will open windows with a preset size and position.  I'd like to do this with apps, as well as with finder windows.

For example, I want to open Sublime and have it take up the top half of my screen, and open Chrome taking up the bottom half of my screen.
Another example is I'd like to open up four finder windows, each taking up a quarter of the screen.

Comment: You can do this with AppleScript, but it will require that you trigger the script.  That is, it won't automatically run itself when you open *Finder* or *Chrome*.  If you wanted a fully automated solution, there are various programs that can trigger AppleScripts to run when they detect an occurrence of an event, e.g. when an application opens.  Such programs include [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) and [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net).

Comment: CJK, thanks so much for your suggestions.  Actually, I want to create a script I can click to make this happen. I don’t want it to happen automatically when I open the app.  Could you point me in the direction of how to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using *Script Editor* to write some AppleScripts that will cater to your different layout requirements for different applications.

I'll demonstrate how this can be done using your first example featuring *Sublime* and *Google Chrome*, which are to occupy the top half and the bottom half of the screen, respectively.

This script assumes the applications are already running with a visible window available in each application to manipulate.  It's actually a very short script, but looks long because of the comment lines (they start with `--`) that I inserted at each stage to guide you through what each part of the script does:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        set Chrome to the front window of application process "Google Chrome"
        set Sublime to the front window of application process "Sublime Text"

        -- Get the size of the screen's display in pixels
        get the size of scroll area 1 of application process "Finder"
        set Display to {width:item 1, height:item 2} of the result

        -- First attempt to make Sublime take up the full width and
        -- height of the display. 
        set position of Sublime to [0, 0]
        set size of Sublime to [the Display's width, the Display's height]

        -- However, the presence of a visible menu bar and dock
        -- will create natural barriers that the window won't cross.

        -- Retrieve the actual size and position that Sublime's
        -- window ended up adopting.
        set [_w, _h] to the size of Sublime
        set [_x, _y] to the position of Sublime

        -- Half Sublime's window's height.  It should now be
        -- correctly positioned and sized.
        set the size of Sublime to [_w, _h / 2 - 1]

        -- Position Chrome first so that its horizontally aligned
        -- with Sublime, and the top edge of Chrome's window's meets 
        -- the bottom edge of Sublime's.
        set position of Chrome to [_x, _y + _h / 2]
        -- Then size Chrome's window identically to that of Sublime.
        set size of Chrome to [_w, _h / 2 - 1]
    end tell


    -- Lastly, bring both applications to the foreground
    activate application "Sublime Text"
    activate application "Google Chrome"
```

Bear in mind this is just a quick example of how you might approach this task given an optimal starting point (both apps open with one active window each).  However, you'll likely want to incorporate ways of dealing with less optimal situations, such as how you'd want your script to behave if you accidentally triggered it before opening *Chrome*; or if you wished to arrange four *Finder* windows into separate corners of the screen, but there were five open at the time.

---

Alternatively, you could spend about $1 and get an app from the *App Store* that will size and position windows in just about any arrangement you could wish for.  Here's one:

- [Magnet](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/magnet/id441258766?mt=12)

Comment: CJK, thanks.  I'm going to try this out after work this evening. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: CJK, it works! Your example is a really good way to see how easy it is to use script editor.  It's basically writing what you want the computer to do. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what Apple had in mind when they developed AppleScript: they wanted a "natural language" code that would be easy to write in.  Unfortunately, it's quite a temperamental language and has some annoyances that have made it very unpopular.  I, personally, love it; but it's losing favour and I'm not sure how long it'll continue to be around with the likes of JavaScript, Swift and Objective-C capable of doing so much more in terms of application scripting.

Answer (score 0):

At least on **Sublime** I addressed this issue by following these three simple steps

1. Put this on the `Preferences.sublime-preferences`

```rb
"remember_full_screen": true
```

2. Open the sublime
3. Resize **MANUALLY** the sublime window to the size you want (maximum height and width)

☝️

After I followed this steps, now everytime I open the sublime (even with `subl`), the sublime opens on the last window that I **MANUALLY** resized it.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnVaughters No problem John, did it work? :) Any doubt you can contact right here.